# OCMock: Setting expectations on properties

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

How do I set an expectation on a property of an instance?

Let's say I have the following code:

```
id request = OCMClassMock([NSMutableURLRequest class]);
```

And I want to make sure that, in my implementation, the HTTPMethod property is set to `@"Get"`, how would my test verify this?

Comment: Why not simply pass a real instance of `NSMutableURLRequest` and assert that it has the correct HTTP method set?

Comment: I agree with @Fönsi -- consider mocking `NSURLConnection` but I'd leave the request as a real object.

Comment: In that case, how do I verify the NSMutableURLRequest object that is passed to the mocked NSURLConnection? Do I do this via a callback of some sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
- (void)testNSURLConnection
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    id connectionMock = OCMClassMock([NSURLConnection class]);
    OCMStub([connectionMock connectionWithRequest:[OCMArg checkWithBlock:^BOOL(NSMutableURLRequest *request) {
        XCTAssertTrue([request.HTTPMethod isEqualToString:@"GET"]);
        return YES;
    }] delegate:OCMOCK_ANY]);

    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:nil];
}
```

This test will fail until your change `@"POST"` to `@"GET"` which is, I believe, what you want.

Comment: That was incredibly helpful. This is my first real attempt at Obj-C/TDD I'm coming over from C# (and it's tools, e.g. Moq), so I'm trying to learn/get used to the syntax in this side of the world. Much, much appreciated, my friend.